# How to make rgb LED strip digitally addressable

Tags: arduino, pwm, led-strip, ws2812b

I'm planning to install rgb LEDs srip on each steps of stair, there are total of 19 steps and I want to control each strip individually so I need 3 for rgb and 19  for each strip that makes 57 pwn signals so instead I want to make circuit for each strip and control all strips with 1 or 2 control signals from arduino something like ws2812. Any suggestions?

P.s led strip is 12v, currently I'm using n channel power mosfet in switching mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a microcontroller on each strip.  That does the PWM locally for each color of that strip.  You don't want to run PWM lines a long distance anyway.  The signals will be messy at the ends of the wires, and they would emit a lot of RF interference.

Use a micro with CAN built in.  Connect all the strips to a single CAN bus, with a separate master that tells each of the strips what to do at a high level.

It would be convenient to use the same cable for CAN and power.  In that case, you might want to bus around something like 24 V.  That way each strip can make its own 12 V.  With 24 V, there will be less voltage drop along the cable, and with individual buck switchers on each strip, the bus voltage can be anything over a reasonably wide range.  It should be easily possible to tolerate anywhere from maybe 14 V to up to 30 V in at each strip.

Comment: Putting 19 microcontrollers doesn't seems to be cost effective and I m planning to use esp32 which is more expensive than arduino

Comment: @Uza: Microcontrollers are cheap.  A small micro that has 3 PWM outputs (most of them) and CAN (many of them) should be significantly cheaper than the LED strip it will control.  Also, this sounds like a one-off project, so everything is a one-time cost.

Comment: Can I use attiny

Comment: @Uza: I told you what a micro would need to do.  Read the datasheet and see if any micrco you are contemplating does those things.

Answer (score 3):

Put one [WS2801](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2801.pdf) chip on each strip. This avoids the need to program a generic microcontroller, as well as some of the external components it needs. You'll still need external driver transistors for the LEDs (same as the micro), as well as the local power regulation that Olin is describing.